# Backbone collection working with Rest not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, backbone.js, requirejs

When i actually console.log(this.collection.fetch()) you can see in the responceJSON and responseText that it's returned the correct data from the api.

However, my readyState always remain as 1 and when i run

```
this.collection.fetch({
    success : function() {
         console.log(that.collection.toJSON())
    }
});
```

it returns a blank array even though we no the sever has responded with data.

Here's my code...

Model

```
define(['backbone'], function(backbone){

    var google_place = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults : {
            'title'     : 'no titile',
            'sub_title' : 'no subtitle',
            'content'   : 'no content available',
            'lat'       :  0,
            'lng'       :  0,
            'text'      : 'no text'
        }

    });

    return google_place;


});
```

Collection

```
define(['../model/google_place'], function(google_place){

    var google_places = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: google_places,

        initialize: function(models, options) {

        },

        url: function() {
            return "http://globallcoach-app.dev/api/";
        },

        parse: function(data) {
            return data.items;
        },

    });

    return google_places;

});
```

View

```
define(includes(), function(backbone, mustache){

    var index = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize : function() {
            this.template = mustache.render(nav);
        },

        render : function() {
            var that = this;
            console.log(that.collection.fetch());
            this.collection.fetch({
                success : function() {
                    console.log(that.collection.toJSON())
                },

            });

            return;
        },

    });

    return index;

});
```

JSON Response from fetch (responseText)

```
[{
    "title": "no titile",
    "sub_title": "no subtitle",
    "content": "no content available",
    "lat": "0",
    "lng": "0",
    "text": "no text"
}, {
    "title": "Example Title",
    "sub_title": "Example Subtitle",
    "content": "Loads on content here",
    "lat": "0",
    "lng": "0",
    "text": "random text bullshit"
}]
```

Comment: What is the format of the response you see? Can you post the json? Are you sure the parse function in google_places is necessary? Is there really an items array in the response?

Comment: I have put an edit it with the response

Comment: It looks like you don't need the parse function since the top level of the response json is already an array of google_places.

Answer (score 2):

Your collections `parse` method contains the following:

```
parse: function(data) {
   return data.items;
},
```

but the response doesn't have an `items` property:

```
[{
  "title": "no titile",
  "sub_title": "no subtitle",
  "content": "no content available",
  "lat": "0",
  "lng": "0",
  "text": "no text"
 }, {
  "title": "Example Title",
  "sub_title": "Example Subtitle",
  "content": "Loads on content here",
  "lat": "0",
  "lng": "0",
  "text": "random text bullshit"
}]
```

Hence `parse` returns undefined, `collection.toJSON()` returns empty array

---

Either you should remove the `parse` method or your response should be

```
{
  "items":     [{
    "title": "no titile",
    "sub_title": "no subtitle",
    "content": "no content available",
    "lat": "0",
    "lng": "0",
    "text": "no text"
   }, {
    "title": "Example Title",
    "sub_title": "Example Subtitle",
    "content": "Loads on content here",
    "lat": "0",
    "lng": "0",
    "text": "random text bullshit"
  }]
}
```

Also your collection doesn't seem to be importing `backbone`. Make sure it has access to `Backbone` and isn't throwing any error

Comment: Wasn't the route of the problem but it helped me solve the issue never the less so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parse function. The JSON is already an array of google_places.